# C# Cancel a list of tasks which are executing long running sql queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

I need to cancel a list of tasks that are running SQL queries after the wait time expires. I can implement CancellationToken to cancel the tasks. But the Cancellation is cooperative, so it means I have to check the cancel token status inside my action before every step. But in my case the sql queries are the ones that take long time, and I can only check the cancel token status before or after the query execution. In the later case it is useless, so how do I cancel the query execution inside these tasks based on the cancel token status?

```
public void EnqueueTask(Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var task = new Task(action, cancelToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    if (_workTaskQueue.TryAdd(task))
    {
        TaskHandler?.Invoke
            (new TaskProcessingArguments
            {
                ISTaskAdded = true,
                Message = "Task Added to Queue",
                PendingTaskCount = _workTaskQueue.Count,
            });
    }
    else
    {
        TaskHandler?.Invoke
            (new TaskProcessingArguments
            {
                ISTaskAdded = false,
                Message = "Timedout while adding Task to Queue",
                PendingTaskCount = _workTaskQueue.Count,
            });
    }
}

public void DequeueTask(int maxConcurrency, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    using (SemaphoreSlim concurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency))
    {
        foreach (var task in _workTaskQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            try
            {
                if (!(task.IsCanceled) && task.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
                {
                    tasks.Add(task);
                    task.Start();
                }
            }
            finally {
                concurrencySemaphore.Release();
            }
        }
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

    void StartWorker()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                taskQueue.DequeueTask(maxConcurrency, cancellationToken);
            }
            finally {
                lock (syncObj)
                {
                    IsCompleted = true;
                }
                //Logger.Info("Closing Worker task!!!");
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
```

Comment: it depends on your code, what do you use to execute the querys? Sometimes it is possible to pass a cancellationToken to the async method as a parameter. 
Remember: Canceling a SQL query after a certain time should better be by passing a timeout (miliseconds) to where the query is executed from (and not a cancellationtoken). You only would use cancellationtoken's if you don't know, when to stop (ex. the user wants to stop it.)

Comment: Maerlin, I have added some sample code. I do already have individual time out for sql query, but I am running the tasks in small batches using semaphore, so say each query in a batch times out after 10 sec and there are 10 batches like that, that would equal to a 100 sec run time, Instead I want to cancel execution of all tasks after 10 seconds.

Comment: Read the excellent blog from [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/) which has a lot of articles about async operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **CancellationToken** inside of functions passed as **Action** instances to **EnqueueTask** method.

E.g. the following code shows how **CancellationToken** can be used for terminating execution of SQL commands:

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        using (cancellationToken.Register(() => cmd.Cancel()))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll want to put a using block around that cancellationToken.Register that closes right after the `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: Thanks @Tim, fixed.

Comment: u Show cancellationToken but you don't show what class or function it belongs to

Answer (score 0):

Write a task that uses a new Thread to launch the query, the task can continue checking the status of your CancelationToken and kill the thread if needed.

You can extend Task<> and add this functionality for instance.

Comment: r1verside, this also solved my problem but I am going with Olexiy's answer as it seems more simple. Thank you. Couldn't give you a +1 because I dont have enough reps :|